# How to get all xml files in a directory that satisfy attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to C# and I'm currently working on a side project to better my skills at it and I'm dealing with a bunch of XML data. I was wondering if there was a way to find XML files under a certain directory that satisfy certain attributes e.g. all cities that start with an I, or all phone numbers from the range 1000000000 - 1111111111. I have been looking up Linq to XML because that seems to be what a lot of people use when it comes to XML parsing in C# but I don't know what to use. Any help would be appreciated.

My initial approach is to:
Open each XML file in the directory and look up said attribute, and if they match move or make a copy of the XML file into a different directory, and loop until I check all the files in the directory. Hopefully there's a smarter and faster way of figuring this out? Maybe put on a list all the XML filenames that satisfy the attribute?

Thank you!

Edit: Sample XML Structure:

```
`<DallasMavericks>
  <Players>
    <Name>Dirk Nowitzki</Name>
    <Age>36</Age>
    <Height>7 foot</Height>
    <Weight>245 lbs</Weight>
    <YearsPlayed>16</YearsPlayed>
  </Players>
</DallasMavericks>`
```

and on a different XML File I could have

```
`<SanAntonioSpurs>
  <Players>
    <Name>Tim Duncan</Name>
    <Age>38</Age>
    <Height>6 foot 11 inches</Height>
    <Weight>256 lbs</Weight>
    <YearsPlayed>17</YearsPlayed>
  </Players>
</SanAntonioSpurs>`
```

and the idea is to search for the XML files with say players with Years Played > 15, or players who are >30 years old.

Edit 2: I'm barely starting so this is what I'm heading towards in terms of code:

```
// check all xml files in the directory
foreach (string xmlFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "#.xml"))
{
    // read all xml files
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile);
}

// attribute we are using
int age = 30;

// check to see if Age attribute is greater than age 
var query = from age in xmlFile.Root.Elements("Age")
                 where (int)age.Attribute("Age") > age
                 select (int)age.Attribute("Age");

var files = query.ToList();
```

Now I'm still looking to see what to do next. Any thoughts if I'm in the right direction or totally wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(<sourcedirectory>, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
    var result = doc.Descendants("YearsPlayed").Any(yearsplayed => Convert.ToInt32(yearsplayed.Value) > 15);
    // Copy file.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (string xmlFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.xml"))
{
    // read all xml files
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile);
}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).